# can't resolve method 'show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager,java.lang.String)'

Tags: android, fragment, timepicker

In TimePickerDailog giving me error like Cannot resolve method'show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)'

I get this tutorial from another website i tried  but not getting the output and getting the same error.
 And I refer same questions in stackoverflow but not getting the result so i posted the question.

In this line giving me error :-

```
    dFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"Time Picker");
```

Here the code :-

```
  public class Daily_Task extends Fragment {
    public Daily_Task() {};
    Button submittask;
    View view;

    EditText starttime, endtime;
    EditText Taskname, Detail;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_daily__task, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("Task");
        starttime = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.start_time);
        endtime = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.End_time);
        submittask = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_task_button);

        starttime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Initialize a new time picker dialog fragment
                DialogFragment dFragment = new TimePickerFragment();

                // Show the time picker dialog fragment
                dFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"Time Picker");

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

**TimePickerFragment.java**

```
  package com.Weal.sachin.omcom;

/**
 * Created by sachin on 2/1/2017.
 */

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.Dialog;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // Get a Calendar instance
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Get the current hour and minute
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        /*
            Creates a new time picker dialog with the specified theme.

                TimePickerDialog(Context context, int themeResId,
                    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener,
                    int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView)
         */

        // TimePickerDialog Theme : THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
        TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT,this,hour,minute,false);

        // TimePickerDialog Theme : THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK
        TimePickerDialog tpd2 = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK,this,hour,minute,false);

        // TimePickerDialog Theme : THEME_HOLO_DARK
        TimePickerDialog tpd3 = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK,this,hour,minute,false);

        // TimePickerDialog Theme : THEME_HOLO_LIGHT
        TimePickerDialog tpd4 = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,this,hour,minute,false);

        // TimePickerDialog Theme : THEME_TRADITIONAL
        TimePickerDialog tpd5 = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL,this,hour,minute,false);

        // Return the TimePickerDialog
        return tpd;
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute){
        // Do something with the returned time
        TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.start_time);
        tv.setText("HH:MM\n" + hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this

For `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`

```
dFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"Time Picker");
```

For `android.app.DialogFragment`

```
dFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),"Time Picker");
```

And the activity which holds this fragment should extend `AppCombatActivity`

Comment: i used this and its work dFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),"Time Picker");

Comment: this is working but i want to set Am Pm also can you please help me for this also?? but it is displaying in 24 hours format @Trucket

Comment: for 12 hour format use `calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)`

Comment: No it is giving me output in 24 hour format only... here in dialog when i select  am pm then it is giving me 24 hours format only..